# How to use Unicode in C++ Setfill()

Tags: c++, unicode

*Update #2:* Unicode cannot be used in a Setfill. Searching for alternatives now.

Thank you to everyone who helped!

*Update:* Thanks to jkb I realized I was using a pointer. However, now I am still stuck on how I would put unicode into a `char` in order to use in `SetFill()`. That is my new question.

---

**Original Question:**

I am attempting to use a [Unicode Character](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2501) for my Setfill() but I do not understand why this does not work.
Setfill() wants a Char and 'line' is a Char that displays just fine in std::cout. However I get the error: *"wrong character type for setfill"*.

`char line =  u8"\u2501";`

`cout << setfill(line) << setw(10) << "┛";` // Error: wrong character type for setfill

`cout << line << endl;` // Displays line correctly

I have searched for things relating to using Unicode in Setfill but I didn't see anything close to what I need. I have tried the code above and I directly pasted the character: `Setfill('━')` but it did not work.

I would appreciate a nod in the right direction as I am stuck.

Thank you in advance!

---

edit: I have changed the first line of code based on what jkb said:

> line is not a char type, it is a char * (pointer) type. – jkb

it used to be this:

`const char* line =  u8"\u2501";`

Comment: `line` is not a `char` type, it is a `char *` (pointer) type.

Comment: `u8"\u2501"` is a `char8_t[4]`, not a `char`, and there's no way to pass a Unicode character to it because code points > 127 needs more than 1 byte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unicode has various formats. UTF-8 is a format that encodes most typical English characters in a single byte. However, to encode many of the tens of thousands of Unicode characters requires more than a single byte.

However, the `setfill()` adapts to the stream it is used with. cout is not a wide character (UTF-16, 16 bit, 2 byte) stream. So the character you've chosen doesn't fit.

As provided in another answer. The following code will likely meet your need.

```
std::wcout << std::setfill(L'\u2501') << std::setw(10) << L'\u251b' << std::endl;
```

The function `wcout` is the wide character version of `cout`.

Comment: Thank you for specifying that Setfill cannot be used with Unicode. I am still new to C++ so I thought there was something I could do to make it work or force it. I will look for an alternative now. Also, I am working for this to work on Windows not Linux, sorry about that. I did not think to include that in my question.

Comment: Corrected my answer, based on Chris Dodd's excellent input.

Comment: "16 bit, 2 byte" This is implementation-dependent.

Comment: there are no such things are "Unicode-8" or "Unicode-16". Unicode is just a charset, i.e. a map from a number (called code point) to a glyph. That number is encoded in various ways (encoding) called UTF-1, 7, 8, 9, 16, 32...

Comment: Are there implementations that use cout for UTF-16? I wasn't aware of that. Do you have an example? I have to admit most of my experience is on Windows and a bit of 8 bit embedded systems. (Comment corrected, for UTF/Unicode terminology, based on phuclv's comment). Thanks phuclv.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to output wide characters, you need to use a wostream.

```
std::wcout << std::setfill(L'\u2501') << std::setw(10) << L'\u251b' << std::endl;
```

should do what you want.

One thing that you may need on Linux to get the locale set up properly:

```
std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
```

called in `main` before trying to output anything.  Without this, it will use the default C locale which doesn't support unicode.

Comment: I have attempted to use this and nothing from this line will appear on the console for me still. I will look into `wcout` more now though to troubleshoot. Thanks Chris.

Comment: Try std::wcout << _T("Hello world\n"); or std::wcout << L"Hello World\n"); as a starting point.

Comment: even with a wide stream you may not be able to work with characters outside the BMP